# passenger start standalone with RAILS_ENV=production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I'm trying to run multiple rails apps (different versions) on my server. I followed this post

[Phusion Passenger & running multiple Ruby versions](http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/)

I ran one app outside the pattern with passenger standalone:

```
passenger start -a 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -d
```

But I got this error:

> database configuration does not specify adapter
>   (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)

So, this app is on the development environment and I want to run as production mode.

How can I do it?

Comment: Did you specify you production db config? I mean `database.yml` file

Comment: Yes! Solved! I passed now this command:

passenger start -a 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -d --environment production

Comment: You can post your answer and accept it. To close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! I passed now this command:

```
passenger start -a 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -d --environment production
```